# Upgrading MonoDroid to Mono 3 or 2.12

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I see that Mono 3.0 (or is it 2.12) just got released in October.  Is that 3.0/2.12 release stable?  How can I upgrade MonoDroid to use it so that I can use C# 5.0 async keywords?  I am currently using MondoDroid 4.2.7

I clicked check for updates inMono Develop and could find only mono for android 4.2.8 beta.  I see in the releases documentation that there is also a 4.4 release.  Is there a monodroid release that uses the latest mono release.  If not, is it stable/easy to swap it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current 3.0.0 release is a beta release (there is no fixed date for a stable release yet).

You can't change the Mono version Mono for Android (or MonoTouch) use yourself, those products embed Mono themselves (the Mono runtime and Mono for Android / MonoTouch are tied together very tightly, so it's not just a matter of switching between Mono versions).

The current plan is to release a Mono 3.0-based Mono for Android / MonoTouch some time early next year.